# Sending Email from Android with Qt

Tags: android, qt, email

I use Qt 5.10.1 and Android 6.

If execute the C++ (Qt) code on Android:

```
QDesktopServices :: openUrl (QUrl ("mailto:?to=info@mail.com&subject=Question"));
```

Instead of opening a mailer-program (for example, GMail), Android will open a dialog for registering a new email account.

Of course, the GMail account was created earlier and works great.

How to open in Qt an email program to send a letter?

Comment: Have you tried using the following URL format: `mailto:info@mail.com?subject=Question`? If that does not work either, you can always use the nativ android java code and call it via `QAndroidJniObject`

Comment: Your URL format already does not work.